# What is wrong with the following code? I am trying to search for a record in a text file

Tags: c, file, search, scanf

The program runs fine till I create the file and enter records from structure, but when I try to search a record by using roll no, it crashes.

I am using a structure called student to store data and then I am creating a text file and then I use a for loop to write data on the text file. Then I reopen the file and try to search a record using student roll no.

Program runs fine until I try to search the student roll no. It crashes right after I enter the student roll no to be searched.

Can anyone tell me what modification is needed to make the search work?

Below is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>


 struct student {

    int roll_no;
    char name [80];
    int age;

    }st[30],s;



   int main ()

{
int i,n;
char fname[80];
int search;
int found;

FILE *fp;

printf("\nEnter the file name : \n");
scanf("%s",fname);
fp=fopen(fname,"w");
if(fp==NULL)
{
    printf("\nCannot create file :");
    exit(0);
}

printf("\nNumber of students : \n");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("\n\nInformation for student#%d : \n\n",i+1);

    printf("\nStudent roll number :  \n" );
    scanf("%d",&st[i].roll_no);
    printf("\nStudent name: \n: ");
    scanf("%s",st[i].name);
    printf("\nStudent age : ");
    scanf("%d", &st[i].age);

}

fprintf(fp, "\nStudent roll no\t\t Student name\t\t student age\t\t\n\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    fprintf(fp, "\n%d          \t\t %s           \t\t %d          \t\t", st[i].roll_no,st[i].name,st[i].age);


}
fclose(fp);

fp=fopen(fname,"r+t");
if(fp==NULL)
{
    printf("\nCannot open file\n");
    exit(0);
}
printf("\n\nStudent roll no to be searched : ");
found=0;
scanf("%d", search);


while(!(feof(fp)) && (found==0))
{
    fscanf(fp,"%d,%s,%d",&s.roll_no,s.name,&s.age);
    if(s.roll_no==search)
    {
        fseek(fp,-sizeof(struct student), SEEK_CUR);
        printf("\nEnter new name : \n");
        scanf("%s", s.name);
        fprintf(fp, "\n%d          \t\t %s           \t\t %d          \t\t", s.roll_no,s.name,s.age);

        found=1;
    }
}

if(found=0)
{
    printf("\nStudent record doesn't exist \n");
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: also post the input file and example interaction with the program, and debug output

Comment: why do you put commas in your format string for scanf? (`fscanf(fp,"%d,%s,%d",&s.roll_no,s.name,&s.age);`)

Comment: and need skip title line.

Comment: whatever your `fseek` will not work: you are dealing with a file. The size of a record (in the file) is not the size of the structure (with the `sizeof`).

Comment: Also check the while( foef(fp) ). It is better not to use it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: `if(found=0)` --> `if(found == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you're missing an *address-of* operator in `scanf()`, thereby passing an invalid type of argument. Basically

```
 scanf("%d", search);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d", &search);
```

That said, it is always a good practice to size-limit the inputs for string, like, for an array defined like `char fname[80];`, you should use

```
scanf("%79s",fname);
```

to avoid possible buffer overflow by excessively long input.

Also, always check for the return value of `scanf()` and family of functions to ensure their success.

Comment: Note: not seeing this probably means that this user don't compile with warnings (or don't read them). In both cases it is bad :)

Comment: @hexasoft Right you are. :)